# Will ValidateUser() method in the database layer set the cookie?

Tags: asp.net-membership

I want all interaction with the db to occur on the db layer. So, when using the membership API's ValidateUser() method, I call down to it. Will this set the cookie or does it need to be called in the ui layer for a cookie to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be done somewhere where the Response is generated, which is generally in a page class.

So it won't work in a DB layer.